# How can I filter the comment action links so that I can display the actions links based on user capabilities?

Tags: filters, hooks, comments

[image: How can I filte]

I am referring to the action links above. Is there a filter or hook I can use to display these links based on user roles and caps?

Comment: There's a big difference between allowing users to Trash a comment and hiding the link to Trash comments. Which do you actually need to do?

Comment: Shouldn't disabling the user's ability to edit or delete a comment hide the appropriate link?

Comment: Yes, it would, but that's not what you asked. Your question is about hiding the links, which is why that's the only answer you have so far. You should update your question to focus on what you actually want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a hook you can use to filter the action links: [`comment_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_row_actions/). E.g.

```php
add_filter( 'comment_row_actions', 'my_comment_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function my_comment_row_actions( $actions, $comment ) {
    // Filter the actions by user role.
    $roles = (array) wp_get_current_user()->roles;
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', $roles ) ) {
        $actions['foo'] = '<a href="#">Foo action</a>';
    }

    // Filter the actions by user caps.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'custom_cap' ) ) {
        unset( $actions['approve'] );
    }

    return $actions;
}
```

But the above hook only allows you to filter the action **links**, i.e. the items in the actions array (`$actions`). To actually allow/disallow the user from executing the actual action (approving or unapproving a comment, marking it as a spam, trashing the comment, etc.), you will need a different hook or approach, depending on the action you wish to remove/disable.

Comment: Does this actually prevent the user from using the removed action link or just hides it?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it only filters the action *links*, i.e. the items in the `$actions` array. There are different hooks to actually prevent users from executing the actions such as approving or unapproving a comment.